# How do I close a popup window, and open the next page in the main window in ROR?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a popup window containing a form which gathers data for a report.
When I click submit in that window, I want it to close the popup, and open the report in the original window that called the popup.

I think I can open the report in the correct window by using

```
{ :target => <name of window> }
```

in the `form_tag`, but I don't know how to determine or set the name of the originating window.

I also don't know how to close the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

`:target =>` adds the html attribute target to the link.  This opens up a new window and names the new window the target.

You have to use javascript or Ajax to redirect the old page,

```
window.opener.location.href="http://new_url";
```

and then close the old window.

```
window.close();
```

This can be done either through the rjs file or directly in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

How is [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=17785) for starters?

```
# The submit button in your child window's view:
<%= button_to_function 'Save', "$('my_form').submit(); window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup window can be closed using the onClick html event as follows:

```
<%= submit_tag "Go!", {:onClick => "window.close()"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fclosepopup(){
window.opener.location.replace="URL";
window.close();
}
```

It will close the current window and bring you to the next page in the parent window.